# What's the query to get all the indexes in the a Postgres datatabase table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using this query to try to get all the indexes that a table of a Postgre daabase contains but I am getting an error.
What's the query to do it?

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not provide a command like `SHOW INDEXES` to list the index information of a table or database.

However, it does provide you with access to the `pg_indexes` view so that you can query the index information.

If you use `psql` to access the PostgreSQL database, you can use the `\d` command to view the index information for a table.

You could try something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    indexname,
    indexdef
FROM
    pg_indexes
WHERE
    tablename = 'table_name';
```

Comment: Does this work in a Java application?

Comment: @Fabio It's just a regular SQL. I don't see any reasons why it should not work in Java World, whether you use plain JDBC or JPA-based approach (JPQL, etc.) or Spring Data, etc.